# The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED

Tags: java, android, xml, debugging, usb

02/21 08:38:52: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED
Installation via USB is disabled.

The USB Debugging is ON and so is the Install Via USB and File Transfer
I didn't have this problem till now. The weird part is that Other apps can be installed the same way over USB but this particular app isn't happening
I have tried restarting both my PC and Phone

I tried installing it in another phone and still shows the same error while other apps are being installed without a problem

Answer (score 6):

I turned off MIUI Optimization and restarted my phone and it worked. Really cant understand why

Comment: If MIUI optimization doesn't show up, tap "Reset to default values" at the very bottom, you may have to tap it several times for it to appear.

Comment: Yes, you have to tap “Reset to default values” multiple times

Answer (score 2):

Working fine after disable the MIUI Optimization option in Xiaomi. Now I am not getting the popup.

Answer (score 1):

For Poco M4 5G in Developer options, enable Install via USB.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly check the targetSdk version in the android.defaultConfig:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.matukadevelopers.todo"
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 32
    // targetSdkPreview "Tiramisu"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

replaced `targetSdkPreview "Tiramisu"` with `targetSdk 32` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to give install it via USB permission to install the app inside developer mode option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

USB debugging on
Install via USB on
Wireless debugging on

If **Install via USB** is not working, it requires a SIM card. Insert a sim card without switching off the mobile. Hence it will allow you to activate it. After activation, you can take the sim card out.